# Pure php gallery with a dashboard page

Tags: php

So i'm struggling with the creation of a gallery post type in a system fully written by somebody.

Task: I need to create a page in existing dashboard where client will be able to create a page and add bulk images and afterwards display each of them to display in different pages.

My struggle is the way I can make the bulk upload and also the image resize filter. I'm not very experienced in writing a system from null as in the most cases I used cms/framework predefined functions.

Lecture links are welcome,
Kind Regards!